# Taylor Series for Sum of cos(x) in BigInteger

Tags: java

I'm trying to create a class to find the Taylor Series of cos(x) using BigInteger. The class that I am using for this can be found [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/program-sum-cosx-series/). The reason for doing this is I'm trying to apply it to data that has been encrypted using the Paillier homomorphic encryption method which returns a value of BigInteger for a distance calculation I am trying to do. I believe I have followed the series correctly however I am returning a value of 1 when I run the test. Any help would be appreciated.

**CosXSeries.java**

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.math.BigInteger;

public class CosXSeries {
static BigInteger cosXSertiesSum(BigInteger x, BigInteger n) 
    { 
        double PIE = 3.142;
        BigInteger PI = BigDecimal.valueOf(PIE).toBigInteger();
        BigInteger OneEighty = new BigInteger("180");
        BigInteger res = new BigInteger("1"); 
        BigInteger sign = new BigInteger("1");
        BigInteger fact = new BigInteger("1");
        BigInteger pow = new BigInteger("1");
        //BigInteger i = new BigInteger("1");
        BigInteger minus = new BigInteger("-1");
        BigInteger one = new BigInteger("1");
        BigInteger two = new BigInteger("2");

        x = x.multiply(PI.divide(OneEighty));

        for (BigInteger bi = BigInteger.valueOf(4);
                        bi.compareTo(BigInteger.ZERO) > 1;
                        bi = bi.subtract(BigInteger.ONE)) 
        { 
            sign = sign.multiply(minus); 
            fact = fact.multiply(two.multiply(bi.subtract(one))).multiply(two.multiply(bi)); 
            pow = pow.multiply(x.multiply(x)); 
            res = res.add(sign.multiply(pow.divide(fact))); 
        } 

        return res; 
    } 

    // Driver Code 
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    { 
            BigInteger x = new BigInteger("526823224"); 
            BigInteger n = new BigInteger("4");
            BigInteger mill = new BigInteger("1000000");
            System.out.println((cosXSertiesSum(x, n).multiply(mill)).divide(mill)); 
    }
}
```

**-----------------EDIT----------------------**

I have adapted the class to use BigDecimal like you guys said however I am still returning a value of 1.0 from the test variables. Can anyone see any problems?

**UpdatedCosXSeries.java**

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.math.RoundingMode;

public class CosXSeries {
 static BigDecimal cosXSertiesSum(BigDecimal x, BigDecimal n) 
    { 
        BigDecimal PI = new BigDecimal("3.14");
        BigDecimal OneEighty = new BigDecimal("180.00");
        BigDecimal res = BigDecimal.ONE; 
        BigDecimal sign = BigDecimal.ONE;
        BigDecimal fact = BigDecimal.ONE;
        BigDecimal pow = BigDecimal.ONE;
        //BigInteger i = new BigInteger("1");
        BigDecimal minus = new BigDecimal("-1");
        BigDecimal one = BigDecimal.ONE;
        BigDecimal two = new BigDecimal("2");

        x = x.multiply(PI.divide(OneEighty, 2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP));

        for (BigDecimal bi = BigDecimal.valueOf(4);
                        bi.compareTo(BigDecimal.ZERO) > 1;
                        bi = bi.subtract(BigDecimal.ONE)) 
        { 
                    //sign = sign * -1; 
                    sign = sign.multiply(minus);
                    //fact = fact * (2 * i - 1) * (2 * i); 
                    fact = fact.multiply((two.multiply(bi).subtract(one))).multiply(two.multiply(bi));
                    //pow = pow * x * x; 
                    pow = pow.multiply(x).multiply(x); 
                    //res = res + sign * pow / fact;
                    res = res.add(sign).multiply(pow).divide(fact, 2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP); 
        } 

        return res; 
    } 

    // Driver Code 
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    { 
            BigDecimal x = new BigDecimal("52.6823224"); 
            BigDecimal n = new BigDecimal("4");
            BigDecimal mill = new BigDecimal("1000000");
            //System.out.println((cosXSertiesSum(x, n) * 1000000) / 1000000.00);
            System.out.println((cosXSertiesSum(x, n).multiply(mill)).divide(mill, 2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP)); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you converting `PI` to a `BigInteger`?  You are losing the fractional part so part the value is just 3?  In fact, any division in `BigInteger` will lose what would normally be a fractional part in a `floating point operation`.  Perhaps you should use `BigDecimal`

Comment: What is the actual formula that you are trying to evaluate? Using `BigInteger` for exact answers seems inconsistent with a formula involving pi, since that can't be exactly represented.

Answer (score 0):

BigInteger has integer values (1,2,3), BigDecimal is probably what you want if you're doing a Taylor series (0.5, 1.1, ...).